# Can I kill the Golem pre-hardmode?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was wondering of it is possible to kill the Golem pre-hardmode. If so please tell me how to do so and what kinds of gear you need to kill it (accessories, armor, weapons, arena prep). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for tagging Terraria *mobile* instead of PC, as you can break through with Dynamite in Mobile.

Now, to answer your question, you should prepare both with gear and with a plan.

**Weapons**

For weapons, I'd say it depends on what you're better with, though ranged/magic damage, to me, is the better choice. If you're into melee, use the Night's Edge, crafted with Blade of Grass (crafted with UG Jungle materials), Fiery Greatsword (crafted with 20 Hellstone bars), Muramasa (found in the Dungeon), and the Blood Butcherer/ Light's Bane (crafted with Crimtane/ Demonite bars, respectively). As for Magic, use weapons that can go through walls. If not, and you want to use guns, use the Minishark.

**The Arena**

Since you're on pre-hardmode, I would assume you haven't beaten Golem before. Therefore, you can't break the bricks in the temple. What *I* did was place blocks above the altar, exactly where the head can be above, but the body is below. I also put two wood platforms at the right-most area so I can easily jump up to the section I needed. I placed 2 blocks of honey and made a pool on the left, and on the right I had a chest with a lot of Healing Potions in it. However, your temple may vary from mine so you may want to set yours up differently.

**Accessories, Armor, and More**

First off, you need to be able to move. Things like Hermes Boots, Sandstorm in a Bottle, or Tiger Climbing Gear will help. You also need protection, like a Cobalt Shield or a Shackle. Any other accessories you may want you can use. As for armor, you *definitely* need full Molten Armor, made from Hellstone bars. Lastly, get all the healing potions you can find.

**Further Advice for Preparation**

*Reforge.* Reforge, Reforge, Reforge. I can assure you the most helpful NPC you can get is the Goblin Tinkerer. Now, you're gonna need a lot of coins to get the prefixes you want, so those will be helpful.

**The Battle: 1st Phase**

The Battle begins as soon as you use the Power Cell. If you did the Arena how I did, run to the right and jump up the platforms. Pull out a magic wall-piercing weapon and shoot him. The fists cannot hit you but the head can, so at the top right I set a platform where he can't hit me. The head shoots fiery balls of death, which will be blocked by the platform. Keep shooting him until his head is at half health. Then, he will begin shooting wall-piercing lasers, from there, you will need to keep moving and make sure not to get hit, as when the lasers hit you they will take off a large amount of health. Keep dodging the lasers and hitting his head with the weapons. Once that gets to 0 he will enter the second phase.

**Phase 2**

His stone head will completely detach from his body, revealing a mechanical head that will attack you as well. The stone head can be destroyed, but you have to destroy the mechanical head. The mechanical head will be harder than the stone counterpart, so mostly just keep up what you were doing since none of the other body parts will attack you (with the exception of the stone head). Once the mechanical head gets down to 0, you beat the boss and all of the parts die. Good job!

Hope that helped... sorry if it's long.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to kill Golem pre-hardmode because you can't fight it pre-hardmode.

This is because to to be able to enter the [Lihzahrd Temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Temple) where the [Lihzahrd Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Altar) is you need the [Temple Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Temple_Key) which is dropped by [Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera), to which it's [bulbs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera%27s_Bulb) which when destroyed summon it only appear when the 3 [Mechanical Bosses](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanical_Bosses) have been defeated.

To summon the Mechanical Bosses you either need their items which you need Soul to craft which only appear in Hardmode or destroy Demon/Crimson Alters with the [Pawnhammer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pawnhammer) which is only dropped by the [Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh) when it is killed, killing it puts you into hardmode.

Ofcause the above is the Legitimate way to summon it. Under the notes of the [Golem Page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem#Notes)

> - The Golem can only be summoned in a world where Plantera has been defeated. Attempting to summon it in a world where Plantera has not yet been defeated will fail, and a Lihzahrd Power Cell will not be consumed from your inventory.
> - [image: PC Version] In order to use a Lihzahrd Power Cell, you must right-click the altar. Holding a Power Cell and left-clicking will do nothing.
> - Like most bosses, Golem will despawn if the player travels too far away, including traveling back through the Lihzarhd Temple.
> - [image: Mobile Version] Golem currently does not drop any coins, the only reason you should farm him is for his drops.
> - [image: Mobile Version] It is possible to blow the door up and summon Golem pre-Plantera, even pre-Hardmode.
> - [image: Console Version] It is possible to summon Golem pre-Plantera by using the Power Cell when you're under the room's floor.

As you can see there methods to get to it pre-hardmode or pre-Plantera in Console or Mobile Version only. however it should be noted that in the History, version 1.2.3 is when the Golem is unable to be summoned unless Plantera is defeated in that world.

- the current [Mobile Version](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_History) is Version 1.2 equivalent on PC with a number of hot fixes for Android
- the current [Console Version](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_Version_History) is Version 1.2.2 PC equivalent

as such when Console and Mobile Version are updated with the 1.2.3 PC equivalent Version it is more than likely that these methods will become invalid unless there is a method to summon Plantera illegitimately pre-hardmode

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can enter the lizahard temple by using explosives like dynamite before killing plantera I am still in pre hard mode. I challenged Golem and died of the traps. SO BE PREPARED OF THE TRAPS. Use explosives that destroy tiles it won't destroy the temple but it will destroy the door entrance.         But for people in pre hard mode, DONT CHALLENGE OR TRY AND DEFEAT HIM.

Hopefully this helps, Thankyou!

Answer (score -1):

I blew up the door got rid of the traps killed off the mobs used my wooden pick axe to mine the traps went to my mechanic girl got wires wire cutters wire placers and went back built a area that he would spawn in and make a an area to sit at.

Spiky balls on top arrows and flame traps on side connected to wiring with an area with pressure plates and wiring connecting them all.

Spawned him in ran to the pressure plates and ran around and jumped he would die and you would get your stuff.

WITH NO ARMOUR I consider myself PRO at Terraria

Comment: I didn't know playing Terraria was a profession, nor that you could consider yourself to be a professional at it.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, bring a lot of explosives (blocks and dynamite) then get full Molten Armor, and a Nights Edge. Bring wire cutters and a pickaxe and blow the door, disable and mine the traps, place them around the altar, than connect a 1 second timer to them. After that, simply use Power Cell and Dodge attacks, make walls and a pool of honey, campfire, and regeneration potions, and activate traps. It should be dead in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -3):

No you can not fight the Golem unless you defeat Plantera. In order do defeat Plantera you need to defeat the WoF which activates hardmode. After you do that say so and I will give some materials and strategies for the Golem.

Comment: The point of an answer is to *answer* the question.  This does not do that.

Comment: If you would have read more than just the title you would see that the person who asked said "I was wondering of it is possible to kill the golem pre-hardmode. So it does answer the first part.

Comment: So then *say* that.  Don't tell him to beat the Wall of Flesh first, and *then* you'll help him.  That's completely useless information.  Take a look at Memor-X's answer.  *That* is how you answer it.

Comment: I was giving him directions on how to get to fight the golem so that the info will be fresher in his mind for the battle.

Comment: But it doesn't *answer* the question.  The only information you've given is that's useful is the fact that he has to beat the Wall of Flesh.  That's it.  Whether it's fresher or not is irrelevant; he can always review your answer, if he wants to.  The point of answers is to be useful to *many* people, not just the asker.  If you want to add the strategies for how to fight Golem to your answer, we might have something worthwhile here.

Comment: Okay I will edit my answer to include strategies

Comment: Well actually you can summon him through the floor I think. Because I watched my friend get owned win only crimtane armor. And I was only asking IF and HOW

Answer (score -3):

No you can glitch through the walls using actuators and others. ALWAYS BRING WIRE CUTTERS!! Disable the traps will help alot. Most likely you'll die. To know how to glitch look it up. It is also smart to farm him or make traps against him to get the picksaw. Because then you can go into any temple to fight him.

Comment: When a providing an answer like yours, you're encouraged to provide a source. Simplying saying "there's a bug" or "there's a glitch" that you can use doesn't really qualify as an answer. The nature of bugs and glitches are that they will be fixed and is therefor not a good answer.

Comment: It's especially not helpful at all if you just say 'google the glitch'. What is the asker expected to type to be able to get it?